# Como capturar dados de forma correta da lista?

Tags: android, android-studio, lista, arraylist, realmdb

Coloquei o código abaixo no `onCreate` e `onResume`, mas da problema ao colocar no `onResume`. Sempre que volto/saio da tela de edição, o `onResume` entra em ação e percorre toda a lista novamente.

Exemplo: adiciono o item 1, aparece o `TextView` com o valor, volto para tela de edição e adiciono item 2, ao chama o `onResume` e adiciona o item 1 novamente e depois adiciona o item 2 na soma e assim adiante.

Como eu posso fazer a soma começar a partir no item que eu adicionei para não ocorrer esse problema ?

```
@Override protected void onResume() { 
super.onResume(); 
TextView txtTotal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotal); 
for(int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) { 
totalItems = totalItems + itemList.get(i).getPreco(); } txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(totalItems)); }
```

Eu primeiro pego a lista do banco no onCreate, utilizando:

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); 
itemList = realm.where(Item.class).findAll();
```

Comment: Olha eu sempre instancio meus componentes no onCreate. Para falar a verdade nunca vi ninguém instanciando em outro lugar, a não ser que serja um adaptador ou algo parecido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem a sua pergunta, você gostaria de somar apenas o valor do novo item adicionado. A solução mais rápida é só reiniciar a variável de preço e somar tudo novamente.

```
Override protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 

    TextView txtTotal = findViewById(R.id.txtTotal);
    totalItems = 0; // <- reiniciando var

    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) { 
        totalItems = totalItems + itemList.get(i).getPreco(); 
    } 

    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(totalItems)); 
}
```

A resposta longa e mais correta: Você precisa chamar a sua activity de "criação/edição" esperando o retorno de um resultado, assim você pode adicionar um evento que é acionado quando você retorna para a listagem.

Chame a activity assim:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

O "requestCode" pode ser qualquer número inteiro apenas para identificar qual activity que está retornando.
Usando o evento "onActivityResult" na activity de listagem é possível detectar quando retornar para a listagem.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {

    }
}
```

O "requestCode" deve ser o mesmo que você enviou, e ai você pode retornar os valores desejados para o cálculo dentro da intent "data" (bundle).

Recomendo fortemente que você leia os tutoriais do próprio android:

[Como gerar resultados com uma Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Valeu! Deu certo a primeira opção. Vou estudar um pouco mais a segunda antes de implementar.

Comment: @WandersonSouza Marca a resposta como correta para ajudar em pessoas com a mesma dúvida no futuro.